# how to execute every function on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text fields, and validations for both text fields in a different function.And i have a button. I want to call both validation function at the click of submit button.
Whether any function has been executed or not.Each function should execute every time.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You can add more than 1 function to a button like `<button onclick="function();function2();"></button>`

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems pretty basic and has most likely been covered before.

Comment: Make third function, that calls first two sequentially.

Comment: Write another `function()` to call the other two validations and vall this method in your butoon click ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just call out to all the functions:

```
myElelement.onclick = function () {
    anotherFunction();
    andAnotherOne();
    moreFunctions();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do something like:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
   $('#mytextfield1').validate();
   $('#mytextfield2').validate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function func1(){
  // ...
}

function func2(){
  // ...
}

// OPTION 1
var validation_functions = [func1, func2];

$("#mybuttonid").click(function(){
  for (int i = 0 ; i < validation_functions.length ; i++)
  {
    validation_functions[i]();
  }
});

// OPTION 2
function validate_inputs(){
  func1();
  func2();
}

$("#mybuttonid").click(validate_inputs);
```